# PictureEdit image location

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, picturebox

When I use `pictureBox` I can get image location like this (its working fine)

```
using (Form ps = new PhotoSlider())
{
    (ps.Controls[0] as PictureEdit).Image.Location = e.Item.Caption;
    ps.ShowDialog();
}
```

But with Devexpress PictureEdit I can't set image location.

Anyone knows how can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean (ps.Controls[0] as PictureBox).ImageLocation = e.Item.Caption;  ...?

Comment: yes, but there isnt "ImageLocation" item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the DevExpress PictureEdit works that way - I can't actually try this because my DevExpress license has expired but assuming e.Item.Caption is a filename,  can you do something like

```
using (Form ps = new PhotoSlider())
    {

        (ps.Controls[0] as PictureEdit).Image= Image.FromFile(e.Item.Caption);
        ps.ShowDialog();
    }
```

The idea is to set the image property yourself...

Good luck..!